# Stuck at spring tutorial

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I have downloaded,installed gradle and added it to path. How do I create the structure src/main/java/hello in eclipse? I tried to create a basic java project and build it with gradle but the classes folder wasnt created. Have I done anything wrong?
Thanks

http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

```
import org.joda.time.LocalTime; 
The import org.joda cannot be resolved ///// 
LocalTime currentTime = new LocalTime(); 
LocalTime cannot be resolved to a type /////
```

These errors are only in eclipse. I can build it with gradle and the time was shown in cmd.

Comment: Right click on project, then choose option New -> Source Folder, there you can provide the name of the folder and eclipse will treat it well. Not sure if I got your question right.

Comment: I have successfully built it with gradle but why are there still errors in my classes in eclipse? @RestController for example..

Comment: What Errors, you need to post those errors in the question itself for us to help you.

Comment: import org.joda.time.LocalTime;
The import org.joda cannot be resolved
/////
LocalTime currentTime = new LocalTime();
LocalTime cannot be resolved to a type
/////
These errors are only in eclipse. I can build it with gradle and the time was shown in cmd.

link:http://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/

Comment: @John is the issue resolved.? kindly post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok as the the comment added by you, you are able to build the project successfully using gradle. Its just that the error is coming in eclipse.

This is because the classpath of the eclipse project is not updated to include the 3rd Party jars, here joda-time library.

I am not much familiar with Gradle, but assuming its something closer to maven. So like in maven, we have a goal eclipse:eclipse

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

This basically updates the .project and .classpath file with all required jars mentioned in pom.xml.

Similarily for Gradle, you also need to apply the eclipse plugin.

[See this](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html). Hope this helps.

**NOTE:** You might need to re-import the project in eclipse as an existing java project.